# Why mutex is faster than critical section in my code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, mutex, critical-section

DINING PHILOSOPHERS PROBLEM:
The dining philosophers problem states that there are 5 philosophers sharing a circular table and they eat and think alternatively. There is a bowl of rice for each of the philosophers and 5 chopsticks. A philosopher needs both their right and left chopstick to eat. A hungry philosopher may only eat if there are both chopsticks available.Otherwise a philosopher puts down their chopstick and begin thinking again.
The dining philosopher is a classic synchronization problem as it demonstrates a large class of concurrency control problems.

---

I was tasked with solving the problem of five dining philosophers in two ways. With mutex and critical section. that's what i got

---

Critical section:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_STICKS 5
#define NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS 5

DWORD WINAPI philosopher_thread(LPVOID philosopherNumber); 
CRITICAL_SECTION chopSticks[NUMBER_OF_STICKS]; // will save every stick (ecery critical section)
int eatingTime[NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS]; // will save eating time of ich philosopher (in miliseconds)

int main()
{
    HANDLE WINAPI philosophers[NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS]; // will save every philosopher (every thread)

    // init sticks (critical sections)
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STICKS; i++)
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&chopSticks[i]);
    }

    //create philosophers (threads)
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        philosophers[i] = CreateThread(
            NULL,
            0,
            philosopher_thread,
            &i,
            0,
            NULL
        );

        if (philosophers[i] == NULL) // check if there was trouble in creating thread
        {
            std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
           std::cout << "Philosopher " << i + 1 << " Succsesfully created.\n"; // print this message ig thread was succsesfully created
        }
    }

    // wait for each thread until main will end
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(*(philosophers + i), INFINITE);
    }

    // delete critical sections
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STICKS; i++)
    {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&chopSticks[i]);
    }

    // print the eating time
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        printf("Philosopher %d Ate %d miliseconds\n", i + 1, eatingTime[i]);
    }

    // close threads
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(*(philosophers + i));
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

// this func will run the philosophers (the threads)
DWORD WINAPI philosopher_thread(LPVOID philosopherNumber)
{
    int philosopherNum = *(int*)philosopherNumber; // will store philosopher index in integer type
    int firstchopStickForEating = 0; // will store the index of first chopstick that philosopher need for eating 
    int secondchopStickForEating = 0; // will store the index of second chopstick that philosopher need for eating 

    if (philosopherNum == 4) // if philosopher index is 4 (the last philosopher in the array)
    {
        firstchopStickForEating = philosopherNum; //first chopstick is index 4
        secondchopStickForEating = 0; // second chopstick is index 0
    }
    else //if its every other philosopher but 4
    {
        firstchopStickForEating = philosopherNum; // first chopstick is the same index as philosopher
        secondchopStickForEating = philosopherNum + 1; // second philosopher is the same index + 1
    }

    // enter critical sections for the shopscticks
    EnterCriticalSection(&chopSticks[firstchopStickForEating]);
    EnterCriticalSection(&chopSticks[secondchopStickForEating]);
    
    clock_t start, end; // will store start time and end time for eating
    int msecs; // will save the diffrenece between start and end

    start = clock(); // save time to the start

    // eat
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        printf("Philosopher %d Eating his %d time from 100000\n", philosopherNum + 1, i + 1);
    }

    end = clock(); // save time to the end

    eatingTime[philosopherNum] = ((int)(end - start)) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // svae to the eating time array the difference between start and end

    // leave critical section
    LeaveCriticalSection(&chopSticks[firstchopStickForEating]);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&chopSticks[secondchopStickForEating]);

    return 0;
}
```

Mutex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_STICKS 5
#define NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS 5

DWORD WINAPI philosopher_thread(LPVOID philosopherNumber);
HANDLE mutexChopSticks[NUMBER_OF_STICKS]; // will save every stick (ecery critical section)
int eatingTime[NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS]; // will save eating time of ich philosopher (in miliseconds)

int main()
{
    HANDLE WINAPI philosophers[NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS]; // will save every philosopher (every thread)

    // Create a mutex with no initial owner
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STICKS; i++)
    {
        mutexChopSticks[i] = CreateMutex(
            NULL,              // default security attributes
            FALSE,             // initially not owned
            NULL);             // unnamed mutex
    }

    //create philosophers (threads)
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        philosophers[i] = CreateThread(
            NULL,
            0,
            philosopher_thread,
            &i,
            0,
            NULL
        );

        if (philosophers[i] == NULL) // check if there was trouble in creating thread
        {
            std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Philosopher " << i + 1 << " Succsesfully created.\n"; // print this message ig thread was succsesfully created
        }
    }

    // wait for each thread until main will end
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(*(philosophers + i), INFINITE);
    }

    // close mutex
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STICKS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(*(mutexChopSticks + i));
    }

    // print the eating time
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        printf("Philosopher %d Ate %d miliseconds\n", i + 1, eatingTime[i]);
    }

    // close threads
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(*(philosophers + i));
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

// this func will run the philosophers (the threads)
DWORD WINAPI philosopher_thread(LPVOID philosopherNumber)
{
    int philosopherNum = *(int*)philosopherNumber; // will store philosopher index in integer type
    int firstchopStickForEating = 0; // will store the index of first chopstick that philosopher need for eating 
    int secondchopStickForEating = 0; // will store the index of second chopstick that philosopher need for eating 

    if (philosopherNum == 4) // if philosopher index is 4 (the last philosopher in the array)
    {
        firstchopStickForEating = philosopherNum; //first chopstick is index 4
        secondchopStickForEating = 0; // second chopstick is index 0
    }
    else //if its every other philosopher but 4
    {
        firstchopStickForEating = philosopherNum; // first chopstick is the same index as philosopher
        secondchopStickForEating = philosopherNum + 1; // second philosopher is the same index + 1
    }

    // Request ownership of mutex.
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexChopSticks[firstchopStickForEating], INFINITE); 
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexChopSticks[secondchopStickForEating], INFINITE);

    clock_t start, end; // will store start time and end time for eating
    int msecs; // will save the diffrenece between start and end

    start = clock(); // save time to the start

    // eat
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        printf("Philosopher %d Eating his %d time from 100000\n", philosopherNum + 1, i + 1);
    }

    end = clock(); // save time to the end

    eatingTime[philosopherNum] = ((int)(end - start)) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // svae to the eating time array the difference between start and end

    // Release ownership of the mutex object
    ReleaseMutex(mutexChopSticks[firstchopStickForEating]);
    ReleaseMutex(mutexChopSticks[secondchopStickForEating]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

From what i learned critical section should be faster than mutex
but in my case mutex is faster. What is the problem?

---

Comment: Please specify compiler, and compiler options.  If you're timing an unoptimized or "debug" build, then the timings are meaningless.

Comment: You have a data race spawning your threads.  All of them receive a pointer to the same `i`, which may change between the call to `CreateThread` and when the thread function copies the value to `philosopherNum`.  Also the I/O you're doing in your thread functions is likely to dwarf any performance difference between different locking primatives.

Comment: Pass to `CreateThread` the address of a philosopher object (that has the number as a member), not `&i`.

Comment: You say "faster" but what are your actual timings?  It looks like you're using `clock_t` values which can suffer from poor resolution.  Far better to use `std::high_resolution_clock`.  You also don't appear to be timing any kind of meaningful calculation, and certainly not measuring the speed of your mutexes.  The timed section is only measuring a whole bunch of I/O via `printf`.